# Some Python modules don't show up on readthedocs.io despite appearing when generating Sphinx docs locally

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to generate Sphinx documentation for a Python project and host the documentation using Read The Docs. The project code is [here](https://github.com/argosopentech/argos-translate/tree/407b2f46b2517d3ed9e88068cb6883f72011923f). When I run `make clean && make html` to generate documentation locally the documentation generates and has all four of my Python modules:
[Local Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikHXl.png)

I have Read The Docs connected to Github to generate documentation on a new commit and it successfully generates documentation for 2/4 of my Python modules but two of them don't appear. The Read The Docs build seems to run with no errors:
[Read The Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkbVS.png)

My local build has some warnings but they don't seem to be related to the documentation not appearing:

```
$ make clean && make html
Removing everything under '_build'...
Running Sphinx v3.2.1
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 3 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 3 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] source/modules                                                             
/<home>/argos-translate/argostranslate/package.py:docstring of argostranslate.package.Package:24: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.
/<home>/argos-translate/argostranslate/package.py:docstring of argostranslate.package.Package:30: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
/<home>/argos-translate/argostranslate/translate.py:docstring of argostranslate.translate.Language:7: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.
/<home>/argos-translate/argostranslate/translate.py:docstring of argostranslate.translate.Language:8: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /<home>/argos-translate/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] source/modules                                                              
generating indices...  genindex py-modindexdone
writing additional pages...  searchdone
copying static files... ... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 5 warnings.

The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

[Here's a link to the Read The Docs documentation](https://argos-translate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the RTD build log for "warning" or "error".

In your case, the [latest build log](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/11882881.txt) has the following relevant warnings for the two modules that were not documented on RTD:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'gui' from module 'argostranslate'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ctranslate2'

...

WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'translate' from module 'argostranslate'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ctranslate2'
```

This implies a required dependency has not been specified to be installed on RTD.  Make sure you specify `ctranslate2` as a requirement in your project such that RTD can install it. See [Specifying Dependencies](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies) for complete details.

Comment: This was the problem thanks! I had two requirements.txt files one in the root for my entire application and one in my docs/ folder. Read The Docs was only looking at the one in the docs/ folder. Combining them and and setting requirements.txt as my requirements file in Read The Docs fixed the problem.